# How do I add a field after I've run rails generate model/scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I forgot to add a field to my model. How do I go about adding it cleanly? Do I need to re-run rails generate or can I edit a file somewhere?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either you should re-run your generate scaffold/model (will blow away existing code)

or you can add the field directly to the database and your view

Rails3:

  `rails generate migration add_column_name_to_table_name column_name:string`

or

Rails2.x:

  `ruby script/generate migration addColumnToTableName column_name:string`

which will generate a file in db/migrate which you can apply with a 'rake db:migrate'

Then you should modify your views to add the appropriate code to display/edit the new field.

more info: http://railscasts.com/episodes/83-migrations-in-rails-2-0

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The link seems dead, though. I get the Heroku No such app-error. The Wayback Machine gives me some site with arabic text. Does anyone know where to find this information somewhere else?

Comment: This railscast should give you an even better idea than my original link (which I will now update): http://railscasts.com/episodes/83-migrations-in-rails-2-0

Comment: Remember to actually RUN your migrations as well. rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g scaffold Users name:string
```

If i have to add new field in already generated scaffold,

```
rails generate migration add_url_to_users url:string
```

and modify the _form.htm.erb file as

```
<div class="field">
     <%= f.label :name %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
     <%= f.label :url %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :url %>
</div>
```

But my problem is I can save name only not url

Comment: Is it an answer or question, U ended up with a question..!

Comment: @razz : If you are using Rails 4 then you have to add `url` attribute in strong parameters in Users_controller.rb file... in the bottom.